# How to use string literals with a string that has already been assigned C#

Tags: c#

This is my string

```
string test = "255\r\n\r\n0\r\n\r\n-1\r\n\r\n255\r\n\r\n1\r";
```

In order to find n1 in this string I have to do this:

```
string test = @"255\r\n\r\n0\r\n\r\n-1\r\n\r\n255\r\n\r\n1\r";
```

But what if I declared my string like this as its content came from a text box:

```
string test = this.textbox.Text.ToString();
```

How would I then find n1 in the same scenario as the example above as the code below does not work.

```
  string test = @this.textbox.Text.ToString();
```

Comment: You do realize that in your first `sting` "\n" is one character, so there is no "n1" there.  So what exactly are you looking for?  a newline followed by a 1?

Comment: yes thats the reason i use the @ to change it to \\ and n1. so can you help me or not

Comment: I'm not clear about what your asking.  Are you typing in newlines into the text box or are you typing in a backslash followed by an n?

Comment: @ is for **literal** strings. If you type \n in a TextBox, it won't be a newline character, but \ and n. (Why don't you try it out and see what the result is?) @this means something totally different which has nothing to do with strings.

Answer (score 1):

Use Regex

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;


namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string test1 = "255\r\n\r\n0\r\n\r\n-1\r\n\r\n255\r\n\r\n1\r";
            string test2 = @"255\r\n\r\n0\r\n\r\n-1\r\n\r\n255\r\n\r\n1\r";

            Console.WriteLine("First String");
            MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(test1, @"\d+", RegexOptions.Singleline);
            foreach (Match match in matches)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(match.Value);
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Second String");
            matches = Regex.Matches(test2, @"\d+", RegexOptions.Singleline);
            foreach (Match match in matches)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(match.Value);
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In C# the `@` symbol using for verbatim strings. Only when writing literals.

No need to apply it to variables. Just write:

```
string test = this.textbox.Text;
```

Please note that the `ToString()` call is not required.